# ¿Por qué el valor del TextBox se restablece (resetea) al valor anterior en vez de mostrar el error?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Tengo un ejemplo donde bindeo un `ViewModel` con 2 `textbox` y agrego algunas reglas de validación (`ValidationRule`) en xaml y en el código (code-behind). También tengo un `Control` (`UserControl`) que básicamente envuelve un `TextBox` al cual también le agrego reglas de validación (`ValidationRule`).

Cuando ingreso un numero inválido en los `TextBox` que están bindeados (asociados) directamente al `ViewModel`, todo funciona genial, el error se muestra (contorno rojo en el `TextBox`). Pero en el `TextBox` que está bindeado a una DependencyProperty de mi control (`UserControl` `TextBoxWrapper`) el error no se muestra y el valor se resetea (cambia) al valor válido que tenía antes.

Estoy usando Bindeo Múltiple (MultiBinding) con un Converter (heredando `IMultiValueConverter`). Esto parece funcionar muy bien afuera del control (UserControl), pero cuando lo combino con el `UserControl` y la `DependencyProperty` algo "se rompe".

Por ejemplo si un numero menor de 10 es inválido, e ingreso 3, al perder foco, en los dos primeros `TextBox` aparece un contorno rojo marcando el error, pero en el que está dentro de mi control (`UserControl`), el valor cambia al valor anterior (si había un 39 antes de que yo ingrese 3, el `TextBox` se seta otra vez a 39).

Estoy creando este ejemplo para tratar de resolver un problema que tenemos en una aplicación. Esta es la versión simplificada del problema. Ahora mismo no podemos actualizar nuestra aplicación para que tenga un `CustomControl` en vez de un `UserControl`, pero necesitamos solucionar este problema.

**Pueden reproducir el error con el siguiente código:**

**TestViewModel**

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public double ValueNotNull { get; set; }
    public double? NulleableValue { get; set; }
    public double? UserControlNulleableValue { get; set; }
    public bool Factor { get; set; }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <testMultiBinding:TestMultiBindingConverter x:Key="TestMultiBindingConverter"></testMultiBinding:TestMultiBindingConverter>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>            
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">Not Nulleable: </TextBlock>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="NotNullTextBox">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TestMultiBindingConverter}" Mode="TwoWay">
                <Binding Path="ValueNotNull"></Binding>
                <Binding Path="Factor"></Binding>
                <MultiBinding.ValidationRules>
                    <testMultiBinding:ValidateIsBiggerThanTen/>
                </MultiBinding.ValidationRules>
            </MultiBinding>                
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Nulleable</TextBlock>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="NulleableTextBox">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TestMultiBindingConverter}" Mode="TwoWay" x:Name="NulleableMultiBinding">
                <Binding Path="NulleableValue"></Binding>
                <Binding Path="Factor"></Binding>
                <MultiBinding.ValidationRules>
                    <testMultiBinding:ValidateIsBiggerThanTen/>
                </MultiBinding.ValidationRules>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">Nulleable</TextBlock>
    <testMultiBinding:TextBoxWrapper Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Value="{Binding UserControlNulleableValue}" AnotherProperty="3"></testMultiBinding:TextBoxWrapper>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private TestViewModel viewModel;
    private ValidateIsNot validateIsNot;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContextChanged+=MainWindow_DataContextChanged;
        InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = new TestViewModel();
        DataContext = viewModel;                        
    }

    private void MainWindow_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        validateIsNot = new ValidateIsNot(87);
        NulleableMultiBinding.ValidationRules.Add(validateIsNot);
    }
}
```

**User Control (TextBoxWrapper)**

**TextBoxWrapper.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestMultiBinding.TextBoxWrapper"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             xmlns:testMultiBinding="clr-namespace:TestMultiBinding"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             x:Name="parent"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Loaded="OnTextBoxWrapperLoaded">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <testMultiBinding:TestMultiBindingConverter x:Key="TestMultiBindingConverter"></testMultiBinding:TestMultiBindingConverter>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxWrapper" TextAlignment="Right">
            <TextBox.Text>                
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TestMultiBindingConverter}" x:Name="TextBoxBinding" Mode="TwoWay">
                    <Binding ElementName="parent" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" Path="Value" Mode="TwoWay" TargetNullValue="{x:Static System:String.Empty}" />
                    <Binding ElementName="parent" Path="AnotherProperty" Mode="OneWay"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="textBoxWrapper" Path="IsFocused" Mode="OneWay"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**TextBoxWrapper.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class TextBoxWrapper : UserControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Value.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(double?), typeof(TextBoxWrapper),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, OnValueChanged)
            {
                BindsTwoWayByDefault = true
            });

    private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do something
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AnotherPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "AnotherProperty", typeof(int), typeof(TextBoxWrapper));

    public int AnotherProperty
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(AnotherPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AnotherPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public double? Value
    {
        get { return (double?)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public TextBoxWrapper()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnTextBoxWrapperLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddDefaultValidationRules();
    }

    private bool isRequired = false;
    private void AddDefaultValidationRules()
    {
        AddValidationBinding(new ValidateIsNot(87));
        AddValidationBinding(new ValidateIsBiggerThanTen());
    }

    private void AddValidationBinding(ValidationRule validationRule)
    {
        TextBoxBinding.ValidationRules.Add(validationRule);
    }
}
```

**TestMultiBindingConverter**

```
public class TestMultiBindingConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[0] != null)
            return values[0].ToString();
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            double doubleValue;
            var stringValue = value.ToString();
            if (Double.TryParse(stringValue, out doubleValue))
            {
                object[] values = { doubleValue };
                return values;
            } 
        }
        object[] values2 = { DependencyProperty.UnsetValue };
        return values2;
    }
}
```

**ValidateIsBiggerThanTen**

```
public class ValidateIsBiggerThanTen : ValidationRule
{
    private const string errorMessage = "The number must be bigger than 10";

    public ValidateIsBiggerThanTen()
    {}

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var error = new ValidationResult(false, errorMessage);
        if (value == null)
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);

        var stringValue = value.ToString();
        double doubleValue;
        if (!Double.TryParse(stringValue, out doubleValue))
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);

        if (doubleValue <= 10)
            return error;
        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
}
```

**ValidateIsNot**

```
public class ValidateIsNot : ValidationRule
{
    private const string errorMessage = "The number must be different to {0}";
    private int invalidNumber;
    public ValidateIsNot(int number)
    {
        invalidNumber = number;
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var message = string.Format(errorMessage, invalidNumber);
        var error = new ValidationResult(false, message);
        if (value == null)
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);

        var stringValue = value.ToString();
        double doubleValue;
        if (!Double.TryParse(stringValue, out doubleValue))
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);

        if (doubleValue == invalidNumber)
            return error;
        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
}
```

¿Por qué no se muestran los errores en mi TextBoxWrapper?

Comment: No consigo generar un proyecto compilable sólo con estos fragmentos de código. ¿Podrías publicar tu proyecto de prueba en algún sitio?

Comment: @Konamiman - No puedo, que error te tira?

Comment: @Konamiman - Ya se porque pasa el problema, pero no se como arreglarlo. Es por el bindeo de IsFocused, al perder el foco el bindeo se dispara nuevamente y se pierde el error. No se como bindear IsFocused y aun asi conservar el error. No se si editar la pregunta, o responder esta con la razon y postear una nueva :S

Comment: Yo actualizaría la pregunta existente con la información adicional que has encontrado.

Comment: @Dzyann, si necesita que el valor del textbox no se pierda, almacénelo _temporalmente_ en una variable global, para así recuperarlo y setearlo/establacerlo en el campo a bindear; pero, si este campo está bindeado, _asumo_ que siempre cargará el valor consultado en el binding (si es NULL o está vacío, el valor del textbox será vacío)...

Comment: @Dzyann lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: @JuanK - Si, solo no he tenido tiempo de postear la respuesta. En la semana lo hago.

Comment: @Dzyann vamos, queremos ver esa respuesta ;)

Comment: Si alguien me vota en contra, podrian informar cual es la razon?

Comment: Yo te vote en contra, no es nada personal, es solo que no me gusta lo que has programado, copie tu codigo a un proyecto de WPF y pude reproducir tu problema, sin embargo, no pude entender lo que estas haciendo, por que te estas bindeando a 3 propiedades en el XAML pero en el converter solo usas una, por que usar Dependency properties? Que es lo que estas haciendo, cual es tu proposito? No pude resolver tu problema porque no entiendo lo que estas haciendo, de nuevo, esto no es personal y no tiene nada que ver con que no hayas publicado tu respuesta.

Comment: Talvez una vez que hayas publicado tu respuesta se me clarifique todo y quite mi voto en contra

Comment: @Dzyann, Yo te di voto positivo porque la pregunta esta bien formulada (Claridad, formato, ortografía, etc), pero después de analizar tu código me frustré porque algunas cosas no me cuadraron, entonces te di el voto negativo, y el positivo se quito automaticamente, no hay que sentirse mal con los votos negativos, son una parte fundamental de Stack Overflow y ayudan a mantener una buena calidad del sitio

Comment: @ATM - No voy a cuestionar el hecho de que me hayas dado voto negativo, porque estas en tu derecho. Lo regular en SO es que si hay algo no claro en la pregunta, mas alla del voto, postees una pregunta, porque asi yo puedo aclarar. El ejemplo, es un ejemplo simplificado de mi problema. Bindeo varias propiedades porque para poder reproducir mi problema, encontre que tenia que bindear varias, de diferentes tipos, aunque no las usara en el converter. Si bindeo una sola cosa con un converter normal, el error no pasa. Por razones de propiedad intelectual y demas no puedo postear el problema real.

Comment: @ATM Es bastante subjetivo calificar basado en si te gusto como escribió el código o no, creo que los votos negativos se deben usar cuando la pregunta no esta bien formulada o no hay pregunta del todo.

Comment: @Gemasoft Ok, al ejecutar el codigo me sale un NRE, es decir el codigo suministrado no se puede correr, lo cual tambien puede ser una razon valida para el downvote

Answer (score 5):

> Respuesta original en SO:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34204136/why-does-the-value-of-the-textbox-get-reset-to-the-previous-value-instead-of-sho#34217459

La causa de la conducta que se está viendo es específicamente que ha obligado el cuadro de `TextBox`'s `IsFocused` propiedad en su `MultiBinding`. Esto tiene directamente el efecto de forzar una actualización del objetivo de la fijación cuando el foco cambia.

En el escenario en el que no pasa la validación, hay una muy breve momento en que la regla de validación se ha disparado, se establece el error, pero el enfoque en realidad no se ha cambiado todavía. Pero todo esto sucede demasiado rápido para que un usuario vea. Y puesto que la validación ha fallado, la fuente de la unión no se actualiza.

Así que cuando los `IsFocused` cambios de valores de propiedades, después de la validación y el rechazo del valor introducido sucede, la siguiente cosa que ocurra es que se vuelve a evaluar la unión (ya que una de las propiedades de origen cambiado!) Para actualizar el objetivo. Y puesto que el valor de la fuente real nunca ha cambiado, el destino (el cuadro de texto `TextBox`) se revierte a partir de lo que ha escrito de nuevo a lo que estaba almacenada en la fuente.

¿Cómo se debe solucionar este problema? Depende del comportamiento exacto deseado. Usted tiene tres opciones básicas:

- Mantener la unión a `IsFocused` , y añadir `UpdateSourceTrigger =
  "PropertyChanged"`. Esto evitará que el comportamiento actual de base
  de copiar el valor antiguo de nuevo cuando se pierde el foco, pero
  será al menos proporcionar al usuario información de validación
  inmediata como se edita el valor.
- Retire la unión a `IsFocused` por completo. Entonces el objetivo de la
  unión no dependerá de eso, y no será reevaluado cuando cambia el
  foco. Problema resuelto. :)
- Mantenga la unión a `IsFocused` , y añadir lógica de manera que la
  interacción con la validación no da lugar a la copia de un valor
  rancio de nuevo al cuadro de texto `TextBox`.

En base a los comentarios de ida y vuelta, parece que la tercera opción anterior es el preferido para su escenario, como se desee dar formato a la representación de texto del valor diferente cuando el control tiene el foco vs. cuando no lo hace.

Soy escéptico de la sabiduría de una interfaz de usuario que da formato a los datos de manera diferente dependiendo de si el control está centrado o no. Por supuesto, tiene mucho sentido para los cambios de enfoque para afectan a la presentación visual de conjunto, pero que por lo general implicarían cosas como el subrayado, destacando, etc. Visualización de una cadena completamente diferente dependiendo de si el control se centra parece probable que interfiera con la comprensión de usuario y posiblemente molestar a la gente también.

Pero estoy de acuerdo en que este es un punto subjetivo, y claramente en su caso de tener este comportamiento específico que es deseable para su especificación y necesita ser apoyada. Así que con esto en mente, vamos a ver cómo se puede lograr que el comportamiento ...

Si usted quiere ser capaz de unirse a la `IsFocused` propiedad, pero no tiene cambios de enfocar la copia sobre el contenido actual del control si la fuente de hecho no se ha actualizado todavía (es decir, en caso de impedimento de un error de validación que suceda), entonces también puede unirse a la `Validation.HasError` propiedad, y usarlo para controlar el comportamiento del convertidor.

Por ejemplo:

```
class TestMultiBindingConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    private bool _hadError;

    public object Convert(object[] values,
        Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool? isFocused = values[1] as bool?,
            hasError = values[2] as bool?;

        if ((hasError == true) || _hadError)
        {
            _hadError = true;
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }

        if (values[0] != null)
        {
             return values[0].ToString() + (isFocused == true ? "" : " (+)");
        }

        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value,
        Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            double doubleValue;
            var stringValue = value.ToString();
            if (Double.TryParse(stringValue, out doubleValue))
            {
                object[] values = { doubleValue };
                _hadError = false;
                return values;
            }

        }
        object[] values2 = { DependencyProperty.UnsetValue };
        return values2;
    }
}
```

Lo anterior se suma un campo `_hadError` que "recuerda" lo que ha ocurrido recientemente con el control. Si el convertidor se llama mientras que la validación se detecta un error, el convertidor devuelve `Binding.DoNothing` (que tiene el efecto de su propio nombre indica :)), y establece la bandera. A partir de entonces, no importa lo que pase, siempre y cuando ese indicador se establece el convertidor siempre no hacer nada.

La única manera de que la bandera de ser anulado si el usuario es finalmente entra en el texto que es válido. Luego del convertidor `ConvertBack()` se llama al método para actualizar el origen, y al hacerlo, se puede borrar la `_hadError` bandera. Esto asegura que el contenido de control nunca se sobrescribirá debido a las actualizaciones de unión, excepto cuando se ha producido ningún error ya que la última vez que se actualiza la fuente.

Aquí está el ejemplo anterior XAML actualizado para utilizar la entrada de unión adicional:

```
  <Window.DataContext>
    <l:TestViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Nulleable: "/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBoxWrapper" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
      <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding x:Name="TextBoxBinding" Mode="TwoWay"
                      UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
          <Binding Path="NulleableValue"/>
          <Binding Path="IsFocused"
                   RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"
                   Mode="OneWay"/>
          <Binding Path="(Validation.HasError)"
                   RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"
                   Mode="OneWay"/>
          <MultiBinding.ValidationRules>
            <l:ValidateIsBiggerThanTen/>
          </MultiBinding.ValidationRules>
          <MultiBinding.Converter>
            <l:TestMultiBindingConverter/>
          </MultiBinding.Converter>
        </MultiBinding>
      </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
    <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="2"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Debo señalar, en caso de que no es obvio: el `_hadError` campo es para el convertidor de sí mismo. Por lo anterior funcione correctamente, necesitará una instancia independiente del convertidor para cada unión a la que se aplica. Hay otras alternativas para rastrear dicha bandera para cada control de forma única, pero me siento una extensa discusión de las opciones en ese sentido están fuera del alcance de esta pregunta. Siéntase libre para explorar por su cuenta, y fijar una nueva pregunta en relación con este aspecto si no puede hacer frente a la cuestión de forma adecuada por su cuenta.